# How to remove the cells are zero or null from the map

Tags: qgis, symbology, vector, layouts, mapping

I want to remove empty cells to obtain a map map like (b) from the above map (a).
Do you know a simple way to do it?

[image: cell]

Comment: do you want to remove these attributes from your vector-file, or do you want to remove it from the map?
have you done some searching on this page for "select by value" "symbology by category/value" etc.?

Comment: I want to remove it from the map only.

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is to hide the 'empty' cells then adjust the legend so that the first class starts at 1:
[image]

If you want to delete the data - open attribute table and select by expression and delete - here is a screenshot of expression - your expression will be different e.g. *fieldname* is NULL or *fieldname <=0*
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In layer Properties, define a `Provider Feature Filter` like `"value" > 0` - all features where this condition is not met will not be shown on the map. [See documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight#query-builder).

[image]